# Facebook Page Customizations

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Firstly I would like to know which application I can use to create custom tabs like these: http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?v=app_161193133389

Secondly I would like to know: what's the maximum width of the tab content page to design the promo page?

Can I make the page in a way that if people haven't liked the page, it should show this custom page? If they have already liked the page, it should visit the wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tab that you linked to is a [custom Facebook application](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=161193133389) developed specifically for Coca-Cola.  You can learn how to create your own Facebook application [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas) (see the Profile Tabs section), but there are several existing applications that you can use if you don't need anything very special.  For example the [Static FBML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878) application allows you to create a tab on your Page with static content.

The maximum width of a Page tab is 520 pixels.

After creating the tab, go to *Edit Page* and then *Manage Permissions* and change the [*Default Landing Tab*](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14899) to the new tab.  This only affects visitors who have not Liked the page.  Admins and anyone who has Liked the page will always see the Wall by default.  This option is not available for some Pages, including Community Pages, Places, and Pages that have been merged with a Place.